# Rails active record validation for rich text editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rich-text-editor

I am using simple form and wanted to add a validates_presence_of :introduction validation for
user model.

```
 = f.input :intro, :as => :rich_text_editor, :input_html => {:rows => 6}
```

the problem is that by default  html tag br pass in params while saving the introduction of user and 
validation presence not works.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a simple validates_presence_of you can implement your own validation, in your case it could be something like this:

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_each :intro do |record, attribute, value|
    if value.blank? || value.strip == "<br/>"
      model.errors.add( attribute, :blank )
    end
  end

end
```

And then you will have the validation working the way you expected.